# Protractor: custom locators

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have this code:

```
  by.addLocator('Name',
  function(spanText, opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement || document;
    var td = using.querySelectorAll('td');
      return Array.prototype.filter.call(td, function(teg) {
        return teg.getAttribute("Name") === spanText;
      });
  });
```

It's a simple method to search by attribute "Name". But it isn't universal, because it search element with tag `td`. How I can make it independent of marking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any number of arguments to your locator, so after `spanText` you can include for example `tagName`. You can go further and not put yourself in boundaries of using tag-only argument, but any selector which will be supported by `querySelectorAll()`:

```
by.addLocator('Name', function (spanText, selector, opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement || document;
    var els = using.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(els, function (el) {
        return el.getAttribute('Name') === spanText;
    });
});
```

Usage:

```
// find all span on the page with Name="Alice"
element(by.Name('Alice', 'span'))

// find all .row within #container with Name="Bob"
element(by.Name('Bob', '#container .row'));
```